# Virtual Android Machine doesn't load anymore

Tags: android, virtual-machine

I have no idea what happened. I was using it normally just yesterday, today every time I turn on a `VM`, it keeps going on with the loading animation (upwards of 10 minutes). The `VMs` were never slow on `my pc (Core i7)`. In under two minutes, it would completely load with all the applications installed. I don't have any errors because it either `ends up crashing completely` or the VM loads but is immensely slow` ,such that I would get messages similar to :

> Virtual Machine has stopped responding.

EDIT: I tried turning it on again. After 30 minutes the VM loaded with a blank screen. Then when I tried to click on a button in the keypad, it went back to the loading screen.

EDIT: It turned on now but it is slower than anything I have ever experienced before. My AVM was NEVER this slow. I unlocked the phone and this message popped up: "Process system is not responding." I have two options "wait" or "ok". After I clicked Wait, I could interact a bit with it, but then a second message popped up "Unfortunately the launcher has stopped." and I'm back on the main screen.

Comment: You can create new virtual machine.

Comment: they all suffer from the same problems, even the new ones I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I accidentally deactivated the high-performance mode on my laptop. I re-activated it and now it seems to be back to normal.